# Airwatch MDM and iOS Mobile SDK 7.3

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We recently updated our mobile app from Salesforce Mobile SDK 5.3 (iOS) to the latest 7.3 version. We also updated to the latest version of Cordova, 9.0, at that time. No other changes were made to our app codebase except to address any new found bugs as a result of these updates.

One of our customers uses Airwatch MDM solution to deliver our app to their employees. After updating the app from the version that uses SDK 5.3 to the 7.3 version, they reported that they are no longer able to push a config to our app. We don't have any native code to support MDM, as we only rely on the built-in support through the Salesforce SDK.

We utilized a TestMDM solution to test our app's ability to support MDM and were successful in pushing a config to the app. In comparing the config that we tested to the config that Airwatch looks to be sending the one difference we noticed is that the working config had the "Configuration" key at the top-level of the config file. Whereas the Airwatch config had it nested under an app identification key and dictionary. Attaching both configs below.

Has anyone run into an issue like this? The Airwatch config didn't change between app versions, so we suspect something changed in the SDK.

- [Working Config](https://pastebin.com/vPYLXd1w)
- [Non-working Config](https://pastebin.com/2u3LwVyW)